# Submit form not actually receiving messages

Tags: php, forms

I am an amateur at php and I made this simply submit form (see bellow). Now, when I click submit, it acts as if it went through it displays that the messages was received but I don't get any msg in my actual e-mail. The 3 form inputs names are: name, email, msg. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php
$message="$msg";
$mail_from="$email";
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";
$to ='anomanomanom@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$message,$header);

if($send_contact){
echo "I've received your message and I will get back to you shortly! You will be redirected in less than 5 seconds!";
header("refresh:5;url=http://google.com");
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the submitted data either via `$_GET` or, more likely, via `$_POST`, e.g., `$_POST['msg']`.

Whatever you are using to learn PHP is heavily outdated, as it still depends on something called autoglobals. These were deprecated almost 5 years ago. You can find more info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: So, $message=$_POST['msg'] ;; $mail_from=$_POST['email'] and so on?

Comment: Exactly. Also, if you want to use this on a live webpage, be aware of [this](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/protect-script-from-email-injection.shtml).

Comment: I did a little digging and I re-did my form (I put it in the EDIT in first post). Still don't receive an email from it. Also, I will take a look at that injection thing a bit later.